# Tiff: Single pages are not single pages

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, tiff, libtiff

**Question:**
I have two tiff files extracted from a multipage tiff image using Laser Net application. But, *all images seem to be writing as multi tiffs even if it's only one image per file*. Please check following tiff header from a tiff file. **How would I convert these files to "truely" single page using some external DOS command or API?**

> SubFileType (1 Long): Zero 
>  ImageWidth (1 Short): 2550 
>   ImageLength (1 Short): 3300 
>  BitsPerSample (1 Short): 1 
>   Compression (1 Short): Group 4 Fax (aka CCITT FAX4) 
>  Photometric
>   (1 Short): MinIsWhite 
>  DocumentName (74 ASCII):
>   D:\Lasernet\Output\RDSE_002005_16_24_16_879_S... 
>  StripOffsets
>   (87 Long): 8, 59, 242, 5299, 25124, 45177, 65148,... 
>  Orientation
>   (1 Short): TopLeft 
>  SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 1 
>   RowsPerStrip (1 Short): 38 
>  StripByteCounts (87 Long): 51, 183,
>   5057, 19825, 20053, 19971, 21249,... 
>  XResolution (1 Rational):
>   300 
>  YResolution (1 Rational): 300 
>  PlanarConfig (1 Short):
>   Contig 
>  ResolutionUnit (1 Short): Inch 
>  **PageNumber (2
>   Short): 0, 2**  
>  Software (25 ASCII): Neevia PDF/IMG eng. 9.01 
>   
>  DateTime (20 ASCII): 2013:09:27 16:25:09

**TIFF Tag: PageNumber:**
The page number of the page from which this image was scanned. This field is used to specify page numbers of a multiple page (e.g. facsimile) document. PageNumber[0] is the page number; PageNumber[1] is the total number of pages in the document. If PageNumber[1] is 0, the total number of pages in the document is not available.

Pages need not appear in numerical order. The first page is numbered 0 (zero). We've seen reports of some broken applications reversing the PageNumber[0] and PageNumber[1] values.

http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/pagenumber.html

Comment: What is the problem with the files ? Are there any problems opening them in an application?

Comment: @yahia: No problem with opening files. I can open, but I am using these images in another application which expects "truely" single page tiff.

Comment: please show some source code, what have you tried ?

Comment: I am not doing it with source code. I am using LaserNet application (have to use) for Tiff handling. What I have are tiff files.

Comment: then this is the wrong place to ask - SO is for programming... try at superuser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try graphicsmagick, `gm convert badFile.tiff[0] goodFile.tiff`